# Ubuntu 13.04 Teamviewer 8 cant connect

Tags: teamviewer

I have 64bit Teamviever 8 ver 8.0.17147 wine-1.5.19 installed on a Ubuntu 13.04 desktop and I can launch the app and make connections out to other computers without any problems.

When I try connecting to my Ubuntu client from any of my other windows machines with a teamviewer client or my android client, it just hangs at connecting and never connects.

I have tried both the 32bit and 64bit clients and they both will not allow an inbound connection.

Any help would be great...
Thanks
CJ

Comment: I have the same problem. Someone advised me to kill applications which use the port 80 but I need them work in that port. I am looking forward the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it it - 
I removed teamviewer completely and then dowloaded it again but this time I did a manual install from a terminal window instead of letting the Ubuntu Software Center do the install and now its working great...

Answer (score 0):

If you have two monitors, you can't use twinview. When I changed from 2 X displays to 1 X display with twinview, teamviewr stopped working for incoming connections.  Changing back to 2 X displays with no twinview fixed the problem.